# BroadcastReceiver for android os return nothing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

This is little snipet to try BroadcastReciever android but i dont understand wath's wrong.
In fact just callIntent return log. my little brain it's burning.
if somebody can tell me why ? 
Sorry for my bad english !

````
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.plectre.broadcast">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MyReciever" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.plectre"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```
    public void callIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.plectre");
        intent.putExtra("frist", "Intent premier" );
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        Log.i("callIntent", "Tag");
    }
```
public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //String result = intent.getStringExtra("first");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("Broadcast", " Receiver");

    }
```

No error, no crash, nothing !! :=(
````

Answer (score 1):

Create an `explicit` intent by explicitly declaring the receiver when you create the intent. At present your intent is `implicit`.

```
public void callIntent() {
    // Explicitly declare the receiver class
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReciever.class);
    intent.setAction("com.plectre");
    intent.putExtra("frist", "Intent premier" );
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.i("callIntent", "Tag");
}
```

Additional reading: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleExplicit

Also. You declare the intent's Extra as `"frist"` and try to receive at as `"first"`. This needs to be rectified.

You should ensure that the correct action is taken with the specified Intent `Action` in your receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("com.plectre".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        final String result = intent.getStringExtra("first");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Broadcast", " Receiver");
    }
}
```